# Laravel : Authentication fails every time

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, laravel, eloquent

I have created an app with the Laravel framework. I would like to use the built-in Laravel auth system. I have a quite strange problem with it. It always returns false when I try to log a user in with:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]))
{
    Log::info('User logged in'); 
}
```

I am sure the email and password given are correctly registered in the MySQL table which is named `mD`.

In the `app/config/auth.php`, I have correctly set the right table that I use to store users.

```
'table' => 'mD'
```

I also have correctly created required columns for this table (`updated_at`, `created_at`, `remember_token`).

Comment: Is your password encrypted on db?

Comment: how did you inserted your user to the DB ?

Comment: @Ravan No, the password is not encrypted, should it be ?

Comment: @Fadey via PHPMyAdmin

Comment: Here is a pretty decent tutorial on creating an authentication system in Laravel.  You probably have most of it already but it might clear up any misunderstandings.  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authentication-with-laravel-4--net-35593

Comment: you need to hash your password before inserting it to the DB, try to do that with the seeder method Laravel provides. use `Hash::make('myPassword')`.

Comment: @Fadey Hashing the password did the job, thanks very much, I didn't notice that part of the Laravel doc